# Swift 3 Presenting View Controller

Tags: swift3, viewcontroller

I am having a perplexing problem in Swift 3.  I'm presenting a ViewController and, for some reason, the parent ViewController gets loaded again thus causing an error.  My code for loading my ViewController is:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "jobcodes") as! JobCodesViewController
vc.badge=self.badgeNum
vc.jobnumber=self.keysPressed
vc.show=result as! String
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I made sure the identifier wasn't tied to the wrong view and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 static func instantiate() -> JobCodesViewController
{
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JobCodesViewController") as! JobCodesViewController
}


let vc = JobCodesViewController.instantiate()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can only present after viewdidAppear

Comment: Sadly, that didn't do the trick.  My root controller is still loading again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was. The code below was the culprit:

```
class JobCodesViewController: ViewController {
```

It should have been:

```
class JobCodesViewController: UIViewController {
```